# How to generate proper SQL for LinqToSql?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I use LinqToSql to collect some data from the database by object status depending on current user rights. I use extensions like this:

```
Context.Object1.ByActiveStatus();
Context.Object2.ByActiveStatus();
```

I have for now the following implementation and it works great.

```
public class Object1{
    public string Status {get;set;} //generated by Visual Studio (simplified version)
    public Guid? CreatedBy {get;set;} //generated by Visual Studio (simplified version)
    public Guid? LastUpdatedBy {get;set;} //generated by Visual Studio (simplified version)
}
public class Object2{
    public string Status {get;set;} //generated by Visual Studio (simplified version)
    public Guid? ModifiedBy {get;set;} //generated by Visual Studio (simplified version)
}

//extensions in separate static class
public static IQueryable<Object1> ByActiveStatus(this IQueryable<Object1> rep)
{
    return CurrentUser.IsAdmin 
        ? rep
        : rep.Where(ch=>ch.Status == "Active"
            || ch.CreatedBy == CurrentUser.CurrentUserId
            || ch.LastUpdatedBy == CurrentUser.CurrentUserId)           
}

public static IQueryable<Object2> ByActiveStatus(this IQueryable<Object2> rep)
{
    return CurrentUser.IsAdmin 
        ? rep
        : rep.Where(ch=>ch.Status == "Active"
            || ch.ModifiedBy == CurrentUser.CurrentUserId)
}
```

I want to convert it in something like this.

```
public class Object1:IActiveStatus{
    public string Status {get;set;} //generated by Visual Studio (simplified version)
    public int CreatedBy {get;set;} //generated by Visual Studio (simplified version)
    public int LastUpdatedBy {get;set;} //generated by Visual Studio (simplified version)
}
public partial class Object1:IActiveStatus{
    public IEnumerable<Guid?> GetModifiedBy(){
        yield return CreatedBy;
        yield return LastUpdatedBy;
    }
}
public class Object2:IActiveStatus{
    public string Status {get;set;} //generated by Visual Studio (simplified version)
    public int ModifiedBy {get;set;} //generated by Visual Studio (simplified version)
}
public partial class Object2:IActiveStatus{
    public IEnumerable<Guid?> GetModifiedBy(){
        yield return ModifiedBy;
    }
}

public interface IActiveStatus{
    string Status{get;set;}
    IEnumerable<Guid?> GetModifiedBy();
}

public static IQueryable<T> ByActiveStatus<T>(this IQueryable<T> rep) where T:IActiveStatus
{
    return CurrentUser.IsAdmin 
        ? rep
        : rep.Where(ch=>ch.Status == "Active"
            || ch.GetModifiedBy().Any(c=>c.Value.Equals(CurrentUser.CurrentUserId)));
}
```

This solution does not work because LinqToSql cannot properly convert GetModifiedBy() method into SQL.
How is it possible to properly generate sql:

1. what is it required to implement (custom provider or what?) ?
2. sample if possible

Answer (score 0):

```
   public IEnumerable<string> GetModifiedBy(){
        yield return CreatedBy{get;set;}
        yield return LastUpdatedBy{get;set;}
    }
```

this is VERY strange construct that hardly compiles.

1. It has `string` in signature but yields `int`s
2. More correct way seems to be `yield return CreatedBy.ToString();`

Did you try?

```
   public IEnumerable<int> GetModifiedBy(){
        yield return CreatedBy;
        yield return LastUpdatedBy;
    }
```

Comment: Oh, yes thank you, that was copy/paste issue. Of course I have syntax you have specified... .Fixed in the topic. I have also changed int type to Guid? (like it is in my code) and  `c=>c.Value ==CurrentUser.CurrentUserId`  to `c=>c.Value.Equals(CurrentUser.CurrentUserId)`